# Tkinter menu red message saying menu invoke when resetting and exiting

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this and click reset in the menu and then exit in the menu, it gives me this red message:

> ```
> while executing
> "2708519385664reset_option"
> (menu invoke)
> ```

Anyone know why?

```
from tkinter import *

def play():
    win = Tk()

    def reset_option():
        win.destroy()
        play()

    menu_widget = Menu(win)
    win.config(menu=menu_widget)
    menu = Menu(menu_widget, tearoff=False)
    menu_widget.add_cascade(label="Menu", menu=menu)

    menu.add_command(label="Reset", command=reset_option)
    menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=exit)

    win.mainloop()

play()
```

Answer (score 1):

I check your code i get no anyone error. Reinstall your your code edditer or try another code editer like sublime. I check on Python 3.9

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry if my English is not good)

It's due to recursivity. If you click on `Exit` immediately after running the script, there will be no error but if you click at least one time on `Reset`, you'll get the red message after clicking on `Exit`. But I don't know why.

I have a similar issue with `tkinter` and `threading` but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35308783)